# How to search HTML documentation generated by javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm a Java beginner and I see a lot of documentation for Java APIs in similar HTML format, e.g. [Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 8 API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html). I don't see a search option in any of these documents, so when I need to find for example `random()`, I go to **index**, select **R** and use browser to search for **random**. Is there a faster way, e.g. global search?

Comment: If you're using Chrome you can try this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javadoc-search-frame/mfgkihmpcjjnijmkchojlbccbmhcdfcd?hl=en

Comment: Thanks. It is useful, but it doesn't search method names, so it can't find `random`.

Answer (score 5):

The new JavaDoc.Next in JDK9 produces HTML5 output and has a search box. It indexes package names, type names and member names, according to [JDK 9 Language and Tooling Features](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/resource/JavaOne/J1_2015-jdk9-langtools.pdf) presentation from JavaOne 2015.

Comment: The link is broken :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/search.html) is the source you are looking for. (i.e. choose java se 8 api documentation) But I am not sure if it will be faster than **ctrl+f** or IDE support.

Comment: I does help a little, but I'm looking for a general solution, applicable to other javadoc generated HTML files, not just Oracle's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a search box to javadoc, you can check this project:

https://github.com/ChillingVan/LocalHtmlSearchBox/blob/master/README_en.md

This create a search box when generating javadoc. You can also use it to generate a html file used to show a search box.
The search data is parsed from the html files of javadoc. It is saved as json to a js file so that javascript can read it.